# how to set MSBuild VC++ Directories

Tags: visual-studio-2005, msbuild

I have a solution of mixed VB.NET and C++ projects. When using Visual Studio 2005 you can set the "Tools->Option->Projects and Solutions->VC++ Directories" to help the compiler find your include files. When building the same solution with MSBuild I don't see how to pass these settings. The C++ won't compile without this path specified. When building this solution form Visual Studio it build perfectly.

What is the way to pass this path for MSBUild?

Edit: Looks like MSBuild doesn't pass the path (or the /u switch) to vcbuild. Starting from VCBuild instead fails on dependency.

Comment: With Visual 2010 things work more as expected since the user property directories are used. There's no more need to use environment variables

Comment: For latest version VS2013, see my answer in thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654002/adding-additional-library-and-include-paths-when-compiling-from-command-line/28103688#28103688

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To set the include directories, you can add them into your INCLUDE environment variable. You use the same format as in PATH env. variable - you separate paths with semicolons.

To set the library directories - you can do it in similar way, by putting them into your LIB environment variable.

To set environment variables, you simply right-click "My Computer", choose "Properties". Then you go to "Advanced" tab, and there's a button called "Environment Variables".

Or, you can run MSBuild from a BATCH script, in which case, before calling MSBuild, you can set the INCLUDE and LIB variables, like so:

```
set INCLUDE=C:\Libraries\LibA\Include
set LIB=C:\Libraries\LibA\Lib\x86
```

Comment: If this doesn't work straight, try the fix proposed by @CharlesB below.

Comment: You have to add  `/p:"VCBuildAdditionalOptions= /useenv"` to MSBuild arguments so that it takes the INCLUDE and LIB variables

Answer (score 6):

...and also you may like to append %INCLUDE% and %LIB% to your variables to avoid overwriting of them

```
set INCLUDE=C:\Libraries\LibA\Include;%INCLUDE%
set LIB=C:\Libraries\LibA\Lib\x86;%LIB%
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `/p[roperty]:useenv=true` switch to forward environment variables in newer versions of MSBuild. See full article here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/01/11/vcbuild-vs-c-msbuild-on-the-command-line.aspx