# Adding additional library and include paths when compiling from command line

Tags: msbuild, c++builder

I'm trying to add additional paths to be used by my project group during compilation. Since *C++ Builder 2010* uses *msbuild* I have tried looking at the documentation for that and according to what I can find *AdditionalLibPaths* should be passable as a property. i.e

```
msbuild /p:AdditionalLibPaths=C:\FooBar\Libs /t:build foo.groupproj
```

But it doesn't seem to use the paths I added. I have previously noticed that some property names differ between **VC++** and **C++ Builder** when passed to *msbuild* and wonder if *C++ Builder* might use some other property name to add additional lib and include folders?

I don't want to *replace* the existing paths defined in the project but append additional ones. The rationale for this is that when the project is build on our build server some libraries reside in a standardized place that might differ from where it's installed on the development machine.

*msbuild* acutally calls a *msbuild script file* that in turn calls additional scripts including the *.groupproj* ones using the  tag. I know that a new instance of *msbuild* is created when using the  tag so I know that I have to add the property when running that task in my script.

```
<MSBuild Targets="Build" Projects="..\Foo.groupproj" Properties="Config=Debug (property to add additional paths here!)" />
```

**Update:**

*C++ Builder* seems to be using *IncludePath* and *ILINK_LibraryPath* but setting these overwrite the paths already defined in the project file. Since this file is created and maintained by the IDE so any changes to make it append instead of overwrite would be overwritten by the IDE. Which is kind of strange since it looks like it should indeed append the values

```
<IncludePath>..\FooBar\;$(BDS)\include;$(BDS)\include\dinkumware;$(BDS)\include\vcl;Common Components;..\Config\Config32;$(IncludePath)</IncludePath>
```

**Update 2:**

In *CodeGear.Cpp.Targets* I added my own *property* called *AdditionalIncludePaths* to the *PropertyGroup* fiddling with the include paths.

*Around line 251*

```
<PropertyGroup>
        <BCC_NoLink>true</BCC_NoLink>
        <ILINK_OSVersion Condition="'$(ILINK_OSVersion)'=='' And '$(NoVCL)'!='true'">5.0</ILINK_OSVersion>
        <DCC_GenerateCppFiles>true</DCC_GenerateCppFiles>
        <ShowStdOut Condition="'$(ShowStdOut)'==''">$(ShowGeneralMessages)</ShowStdOut>

        <!-- _TCHAR mapping for Uni^H^H^H character selection -->
        <StartupObj Condition="'$(_TCHARMapping)'=='wchar_t'">$(StartupObj)w</StartupObj>
        <ILINK_StartupObjs Condition="'$(ILINK_StartupObjs)'==''">$(StartupObj)</ILINK_StartupObjs>
        <BCC_GenerateUnicode Condition="'$(_TCHARMapping)'=='wchar_t'">true</BCC_GenerateUnicode>
        <!-- Include Paths -->
        <Win32LibraryPath Condition="'$(Win32LibraryPath)'==''">$(BDS)\lib</Win32LibraryPath>
        <IncludePath Condition="'$(CBuilderIncludePath)'!=''">$(IncludePath);$(CBuilderIncludePath)</IncludePath>
                <IncludePath Condition="'$(AdditionalIncludePath)'!=''">$(IncludePath);$(AdditionalIncludePath)</IncludePath>
        <BCC_IncludePath Condition="'$(BCC_IncludePath)'!=''">$(BCC_IncludePath);$(IncludePath)</BCC_IncludePath>
        <BCC_IncludePath Condition="'$(BCC_IncludePath)'==''">$(IncludePath)</BCC_IncludePath>
        <BRCC_IncludePath Condition="'$(BRCC_IncludePath)'!=''">$(BRCC_IncludePath);$(IncludePath)</BRCC_IncludePath>
        <BRCC_IncludePath Condition="'$(BRCC_IncludePath)'==''">$(IncludePath)</BRCC_IncludePath>
        <DCC_IncludePath Condition="'$(DCC_IncludePath)'!=''">$(DCC_IncludePath);$(IncludePath)</DCC_IncludePath>
        <DCC_IncludePath Condition="'$(DCC_IncludePath)'==''">$(IncludePath)</DCC_IncludePath>
        <DCC_UnitSearchPath>$(DCC_IncludePath);$(Win32LibraryPath)</DCC_UnitSearchPath>
        <DCC_ResourcePath>$(DCC_IncludePath)</DCC_ResourcePath>
        <DCC_ObjPath>$(DCC_IncludePath)</DCC_ObjPath>
        <TASM_IncludePath Condition="'$(TASM_IncludePath)'!=''">$(TASM_IncludePath);$(IncludePath)</TASM_IncludePath>
        <TASM_IncludePath Condition="'$(TASM_IncludePath)'==''">$(IncludePath)</TASM_IncludePath>
```

Then I can call

```
msbuild /t:build /p:AdditionalIncludePaths=C:\Foo\Include foo.groupproj
```

This works fine and does what I want. I'll just have to do the same with the library paths. But I don't want to have to hack one of Embarcaderos supplied files like this. That's just ridiculous :P... Isn't there any official property to set for adding include paths and lib paths?

Answer (score 11):

For VS2013, just define environment variables before running msbuild:

```
set "INCLUDE=%additional_include_path%;%INCLUDE%"
set "LIB=%additional_lib_path%;%LIB%"
REM use environment variables for INCLUDE and LIB values
set UseEnv=true
```

Reference: MSBuild/Microsoft.Cpp/v4.0/V120/Microsoft.Cpp.targets

```
<Target Name="SetBuildDefaultEnvironmentVariables"
        Condition="'$(UseEnv)' != 'true'">
...
    <SetEnv Name   ="INCLUDE"
        Value  ="$(IncludePath)"
        Prefix ="false" >
       <Output TaskParameter="OutputEnvironmentVariable"             PropertyName="INCLUDE"/>
    </SetEnv>
```

But looks like the INCLUDE and LIB appended behind additional include/lib directories specified in project properties.

Answer (score 8):

For additionals `include` on VS2019, use the switch `/p:IncludePath=C:\Foo`

To include multiple paths, use double quote and semi-colon on the switch:

```
/p:IncludePath="C:\Foo;C:\Bar;C:\Another;$(IncludePath)"
```

Comment: what about multiple paths.

Comment: @X.Arthur you can do that (note the double-quote and semi-colon) : `/p:IncludePath="C:\Foo;C:\Bar;C:\Another;$(IncludePath)"`

Answer (score 3):

In C++Builder 10 Seattle (current version as of 2016), I was able to solve this problem (i.e. add custom library paths in automated build) by putting additional library paths into environment variable `ILink_LibraryPath` before running `msbuild`. This has to be done by `set ILink_LibraryPath=...`, not by passing property as `/p:...` to `msbuild`.

This achieves additional paths in automated build environment, without replacing existing paths already set in .cbproj files, and doesn't require any hacks in Embarcadero-supplied files.

The only problem with this approach is that the sequence in which individual paths are checked is not guaranteed - i.e. custom paths supplied via environment variable are appended to .cbproj paths or possibly put in the middle, depending on project setup, and are not necessarily put in front, so you need to be careful to not have conflicting libraries in other directories mentioned in project files.

Comment: Very useful answer, thanks! Regarding this environment variable, in case we need to provide more than one value paths then how would the syntax look like?

Comment: @nk-fford separate multiple paths with semicolon

Answer (score 1):

For VS2019, I have test `msbuild` that it will not apply these environment variables of `INCLUDE` and `LIB`, even you have set them. The underlying reason may be that `msbuild` overwirte `INCLUDE` and `LIB` when loading and compiling `*.sln` or `*.vcxproj`. However, it just my suppostion as online documentions about windows/msbuild is very poor to find the underhood reason.

Solution A:
In my solution, I use `CL` and `LINK` environment variables to set the include directory and the lib directory before `msbuild` building the project as:

```
set $env:CL="/I\C:\users\user\local\include"
set $env:LINK="/LIBPATH:C:\users\user\local\lib"
...
msbuild *.vcxproj
```

more about `CL` at [MSVC compiler environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/cl-environment-variables?view=msvc-160)
more about `LINK` at [MSVC Linker environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linking?view=msvc-160#link-environment-variables)

Solution B:
for another possible solution as you have already pointed, you can pass options to `msbuild` like:

```
msbuild *.vcxproj /nologo /p:AdditionalIncludePaths="C:\users\user\local"
msbuild *.vcxproj /nologo /p:IncludePath="C:\users\user\local"
```