# How to debug native Node module compilation on Windows gyp

Tags: windows, node.js, msbuild, pcap, node-gyp

I am trying to `npm install` Node's [`pcap` module](https://github.com/mranney/node_pcap) on Windows 7 with Python 2.7 and VS 2013.

For that to work, `MSBuild` needs to find the `Include/` and `Lib/` folders of the [WinPCap developer's pack](https://www.winpcap.org/devel.htm).

I have tried [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28103688/2228771) to add include folders through VS2013's user-wide configuration file. Those changes are definitely picked up (if the XML is invalid, the build process dies even earlier).

I have also tried `AdditionalIncludeDirectories` (even though I cannot find it in the [MSDN docs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/05/14/a-guide-to-vcxproj-and-props-file-structure.aspx)), like so:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <!-- pcap is at: c:\dev\Include\pcap\pcap.h -->
    <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>c:\dev\Include</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
</PropertyGroup>
```

...but the installer still complains that it cannot find `pcap/pcap.h`.

How can I make sure, it finds those files? (And is it really so hard to just add some system- (or user-) wide include settings for `MSBuild` or am I just being stupid?)

Answer (score 0):

Ok,the visual studio works well on it,there is three steps.
First, you need to build node with debug symbol.

type

```
$ node -v
```

to get the nodejs version,then go to [nodejs.org release page](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/),download the tarball and extract it.

enter the extracted folder, type

```
vsbuild.bat debug nosign x64
```

if success, you will get a Debug\node.exe with debug symbals

Second, you need reconfigure node-gyp with a --debug flag，Let it generate a visual studio solution file.

```
D:\fe\mbox_electron\node_modules\example>node-gyp configure rebuild --nodedir="D:\node-v5.1.1" --debug
```

Third and the final, Open sln file with Visual Studio,and Configure debug parameters.
[image]

then you can click debug button,set debug point,start debug

[this article has more detail](http://computer-vision-talks.com/how-to-debug-nodejs-addons-in-visual-studio/)